# Download function failing with big file sizes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Hi my download function.

```
protected void downloadFunction(string fileName)
{
    string filePath = @"D:\SoftwareFiles\";
    LogMessageToFile("Download started " + filePath + fileName);
    byte[] array = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + fileName);
        

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/x-newton-compatible-pkg";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                          "attachment;filename=" + fileName);

    Response.BinaryWrite(array);
    Response.End();
}
```

When handling filesize of 20, 200mb no problem.

When handling 1gb file, an exception is thrown:

> Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArithmeticException: Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.

What to do?

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: In which line does the exception occur?

Comment: Have you updated your web.config <httpRuntime> maxRequestLength element to have a large value?

Comment: [This is the solution for MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28763549/107625).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that you're running out of memory in the `byte[] array`.

You can try breaking the file down and reading it in chunks.

I found a code example from a Google search to get you started:

[C# file downloader AKA Response.BinaryWrite](http://nolovelust.com/post/C-file-downloader-AKA-ResponseBinaryWrite.aspx)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

public class Download
{
    public static void SmallFile(string filename, string filepath, string contentType)
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream MyFileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            long FileSize;
            FileSize = MyFileStream.Length;
            byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize];
            MyFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)MyFileStream.Length);
            MyFileStream.Close();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = contentType;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filename, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);             
        }
        catch
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Downloading Error!");
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }

    public static void LargeFile(string filename, string filepath, string contentType)
    {
        Stream iStream = null;
        // Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk
        //byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];
        // Buffer to read 1024K bytes in chunk
        byte[] buffer = new Byte[1048576];

        // Length of the file:
        int length;
        // Total bytes to read:
        long dataToRead;

        try
        {
            // Open the file. 
            iStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

            // Total bytes to read:
            dataToRead = iStream.Length;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = contentType;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filename, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));

            // Read the bytes.
            while (dataToRead > 0)
            {
                // Verify that the client is connected.
                if (HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    // Read the data in buffer.
                    length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);

                    // Write the data to the current output stream.
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                    // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

                    buffer = new Byte[10000];
                    dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
                }
                else
                {
                    //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                    dataToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Trap the error, if any.
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Error : " + ex.Message);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Error : file not found");                 
        }
        finally
        {
            if (iStream != null)
            {
                //Close the file.
                iStream.Close();
            }
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();             
        }         
    }

    public static void ResumableFile(string filename, string fullpath, string contentType)
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream myFile = new FileStream(fullpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(myFile);
            try
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = false;
                long fileLength = myFile.Length;
                long startBytes = 0;

                //int pack = 10240; //10K bytes
                int pack = 1048576; //1024K bytes

                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Range"] != null)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 206;
                    string[] range = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Range"].Split(new char[] { '=', '-' });
                    startBytes = Convert.ToInt64(range[1]);
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", (fileLength - startBytes).ToString());
                if (startBytes != 0)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", string.Format(" bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", startBytes, fileLength - 1, fileLength));
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = contentType;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filename, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));

                br.BaseStream.Seek(startBytes, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                int maxCount = (int)Math.Floor((double)((fileLength - startBytes) / pack)) + 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < maxCount; i++)
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Response.IsClientConnected)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(br.ReadBytes(pack));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i = maxCount;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Error : file not found");
            }
            finally
            {
                br.Close();
                myFile.Close();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Error : file not found");
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: If he was running out of memory, he wouldn't get `ArithmeticException`.

Comment: It's more probable that each byte was stored on WORD boundaries causing the array to take up 4x the space.  Thus when he tried to address over 1GB he was actually overflowing the pointer in the 4GB boundary limit.

Comment: The loop isn't what fixes it, it's setting `Response.Buffer` to false.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289200/asp-net-overflow-or-underflow-in-the-arithmetic-operation-when-returning-large-f